# Javascript / PHP - closing the loop

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a HTML form embedded within a PHP file with an onclick button which summons a javascript function.

```
<form name="addStamp">
    Validation Code:<br>
    <input type="number" name="inputcode"><br>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message"><br>
    <input type="button" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" onClick="stampme()">
</form>
```

The function looks at the entry in "inputcode" field and:

- if valid returns the word "**valid**" into the "message" field
- if void returns the word "**failed**" into the "message" field

Script snippet that populates the form:

```
document.addStamp.message.value = msg;
document.addStamp.inputcode.value = "";
} else if (document.addStamp.inputcode.value != test) {
document.addStamp.message.value = msg2;
}
```

What I can't figure out is now how to bring the result back into php so I can use it to perform a `update_user_meta` task.

All of the above happens without refreshing the page and I need to get the result of the javascript function back into php without refreshing the page also.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could either use [admin ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) or the [WP REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) to send a request to the server for the user meta update.

If you have a look at the WP documentation (links above) or similar questions here on WPSE, you can find examples on how to do it.

1. **Update user meta with ajax** https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Update+user+meta+ajax
2. **Update user meta with rest api** https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=Update+user+meta+via+REST+API%3F

Answer (score 0):

You need an ajax call to perform server-side functions.

So in stampme() before or after you show the message you need something like this:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: {
        action: 'WPSE_339452_update_user_meta',
        value: jQuery('input[name="inputcode"]').val() //if that's the value you want to save...
      },
      success: function (result) {
        console.log(result)  
        // whatever JS based on the result that can be true / false 
      },
      error: function (errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    })
```

On the server side you've to define your custom ajax hook that updates the user_meta value:

```
function WPSE_339452_update_user_meta (){
    $_value=$_REQUEST['value'];
    $_user=wp_get_current_user();       
    die(update_user_meta($_user->ID,"my_user_meta_field",$_value)); 
  /* the return of update_user_meta can be 
     true= value updated, 
     false = value not updated since it was the same as the old value 
     in this case it won't update */
}
add_action ("wp_ajax_WPSE_339452_update_user_meta","WPSE_339452_update_user_meta");
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination.  This is so far over my head, seems I really need to go away and research ajax and it's uses.  I think because I could interact from php (html) into Javascript I expected to easily be able to pull a variable back the other way.